# Python extract numbers from text file and total

Tags: python, text, split

I have a simple .txt file named cart.txt that has 4 lines of text and numbers and all separated by commas i.e.
23453, 1, 45.64, white, gloves
25753, 2, 78.32, red, bag
23346, 1, 24.54, blue, club
87653, 4, 76.12, green, ball

I need to extract out the price and then sum the total.  So far I have:

```
with open("cart.txt", "r") as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        part, quantity, price, desc1, desc2 = line.split(", ")[2]

total = sum([float(price) for price in line])
       

print("The total price for the awesome Fathers Day gifts you bought is ${}".format(total))
```

When I run the program I get an error saying that python can not convert a str to a float: ','.
If I remove the part, quantity, etc and do a print on that line that contains line.split, I receive all 4 prices without any commas at the end.  Why is python adding the comma back in which is not allowing me to convert it to a float?  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter all the price, append them in a list, then sum the list,like:

```
with open("cart.txt", "r") as text_file:
    all_the_price = [float(line.split(", ")[2]) for line in text_file]
    total = sum(all_the_price)
    print(total)
```

Comment: That worked!  That's basically what I needed.  It looks like I just had to move the for line down and after the split and I had it backwards.  Thank you very  much!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `destructuring assignments` and getting an item by index from the `list` at the same time, when you do

```py
part, quantity, price, desc1, desc2 = line.split(", ")[2]
```

---

Supposed `string` is the content of your file.

```py
string = '''
23453, 1, 45.64, white, gloves
25753, 2, 78.32, red, bag
23346, 1, 24.54, blue, club
87653, 4, 76.12, green, ball
'''

lines = string.strip().split('\n')
prices = []

for line in lines:
  _, _, price, *_ = line.split(", ")
  prices.append(float(price))

print(sum(prices))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parts = []
quantities = []
prices = []
descs1 = []
descs2 = []

with open("cart.txt", "r") as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        part, quantity, price, desc1, desc2 = line.strip().split(", ")

        parts.append(part)
        quantities.append(quantity)
        prices.append(float(price))
        descs1.append(desc1)
        descs2.append(desc2)

total = sum(prices)
print("The total price for the awesome Fathers Day gifts you bought is ${}".format(total))
```

This is by no means the most effective way of achieving what I think you're after, but it should help you understand the errors being made here.

You're currently overriding `price` every time you read in another line.

Here i've created a bunch of extra lists, and as you read through the file appended each extra piece of data to the appropriate list, then summing is trivial at the end.